# Which microcontroller is best for low power energy harvesting application s?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, sensor

I am going to use a mini wind turbine driven by train induced wind that will generate power. Now I have to store this energy in rechargable batteries with the help of boosters and buck converters. This battery is now used to power my microcontroller that is interfaced with temperature sensor, accelerometer and a zigbee transceiver. My question is how much input voltage is needed to drive microcontroller  and all it's interfaces ? Which micontroller can be used for this application
 That is, take low input power ,but drive all the interfaces.

Comment: This is a shopping question, off topic for this site.

Comment: How much energy can you harvest?  What kind of energy are you harvesting?  How long does the device have to last without harvesting?

Answer (score 4):

The type/model of microcontroller is **irrelevant**.

In principle almost **all** modern microcontrollers (uC) are suitable as they can all be put in some form of low power mode where they consume almost no power.

More than 90% of the power consumption of a uC is determined by **how you use it**. If your program makes the uC active 100% of the time and do power intensive calculations then obviously it will need more power compared to when you let it wake up only one second per 5 minutes to do something simple.

Most uCs work on a voltage from 1.8 V to 5 V. That doesn't mean the rest of the system (batteries etc) should use the same voltage as voltage translation (levelshift) can be done.

Comment: I will add that some microcontrollers are optimised for low consumption in their active mode, while others are optimised for low consumption during their sleep mode. That is the importance of **How you use it**.